# How to allow two classes to use each other without needing a third class?

Tags: class, pascal

I have two classes. They should use each other.
like this

```
classA = class
 // sth
 function change(a:classB):classB;
end;
classB = class
 // sth
 function change(a:classA):classA;
end;


function classA.change(a:classB):classB;
begin
 exit(a);//change the focus
end;
function classB.change(a:classA):classA;
begin
 exit(a);//change the focus
end;
```

but it is wrong. I don't want to use the third because I may use the `"classC"` or even more.

The function must be the class's method.Please don't put it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually easy (unless I have misunderstood your question). Just use a [forward declaration](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#Forward_Declarations_and_Mutually_Dependent_Classes) for the second class, before the declaration of the first class:

```
classB = class; // add this forward declaration

classA = class
  // sth
  function change(a: classB): classB;
end;

classB = class
  // sth
  function change(a: classA): classA;
end;
```